# How does new datatype*[10] returns a pointer to pointer?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, new-operator

I came across a Hash Map implementation in C++. The constructor of HashMap was containing below code. What is the line `new HashEntry*[TABLE_SIZE]` says. I've never seen such a construct before. How does it return a pointer to pointer?

```
class HashMap {
    private:
          HashEntry **table;
    public:
          HashMap() {
                table = new HashEntry*[TABLE_SIZE];
                for (int i = 0; i < TABLE_SIZE; i++)
                      table[i] = NULL;
          }
};
```

Comment: The expression `new T` returns a pointer to `T`, why wouldn't `new T*` return a pointer to *pointer to `T`*?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: I misunderstood that as an multiplication operator.

Comment: What do you mean _how_?

Comment: @DrewDormann That's not really what that close reason is intended for. The issue isn't a typo, the issue is OP not understanding what that syntax means - hence the question.

Comment: @Barry If any answer to a question doesn't have any value to future readers, but only for the OP, then that's exactly what that close reason is for. However, I'm not certain if that is the case here.

Comment: I sort of agree with all three of you. Which is annoying, since you're mostly saying different things.

Comment: @Barry made a convincing argument.  Vote retracted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `new` expression always returns a pointer. A `new` expression for an array yields, according to [expr.new], emphasis mine:

> When the allocated object is an array (that is, the noptr-new-declarator syntax is used or the new-type-id or
>   type-id denotes an array type), the new-expression **yields a pointer to the initial element (if any) of the array**.
>   [ Note: both `new int` and `new int[10]` have type `int*` and the type of `new int[i][10]` is `int (*)[10]`
>   —end note ] The attribute-specifier-seq in a noptr-new-declarator appertains to the associated array type.

That line is creating a new array of `HashEntry*` of size `TABLE_SIZE`. The return type of that expression is a pointer to the initial element, which is of type `HashEntry*`. Hence `HashEntry**`.